# Function to generate a number between two numbers

Tags: ruby, performance

I am looking for a function which takes an input number and returns a number between two numbers

```
 def generate_number input_number, max, min
 end
```

The output of the function should be a number dependent on the `input_number` between min and max.

Note: Everytime it should return the same output for the `input_number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`Random`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Random.html):

```
Random.new(123).rand(1..10) #=> 3
```

`123` is the [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) (your *input_number*), `1` and `10` your *min* and *max* values.

Different seeds generate different numbers, same seeds result in identical numbers. This is especially useful when generating a repeatable series of random numbers:

```
r = Random.new(123)
10.times.map { r.rand(1..10) }
#=> [3, 3, 7, 2, 4, 10, 7, 2, 1, 2]

r = Random.new(456)
10.times.map { r.rand(1..10) }
#=> [6, 10, 5, 6, 8, 2, 9, 4, 6, 3]

r = Random.new(123)
10.times.map { r.rand(1..10) }
#=> [3, 3, 7, 2, 4, 10, 7, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you don't need repeatability (and you usually don't) you can just use `rand(1..10)`. You can also set the global seed with [`Random.srand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html#method-c-srand), i.e. `Random.srand(123); rand(1..10)` will produce the same result as `Random.new(123).rand(1..10)`.